# issue with gmap3 using cakePHP - infowindow

Tags: cakephp, jquery-gmap3

i am working on a project and i need some help with gmap3. i've been looking through the documentation and source code on their site, but i cannot make it work properly. Basically i have a map on my site and i'm placing markers. onClick, i am adding an event to open an infowindow. this is where i'm stuck. i'm passing the values of the marker through an ajax response: this is my method in my view:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
"use strict";
            mapDiv = jQuery('#directory-main-bar');
            mapDiv.height(500).gmap3({                  
                map: {
                    options: {
                        "draggable": true
                        ,"mapTypeControl": true
                        ,"mapTypeId": google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                        ,"scrollwheel": false
                        ,"panControl": true
                        ,"rotateControl": false
                        ,"scaleControl": true
                        ,"streetViewControl": true
                        ,"zoomControl": true
                        ,"zoom": 5
                    }
                },
                options:{
                    draggable: false                        
                },
                cluster:{
                    radius: 20,
                    // This style will be used for clusters with more than 0 markers
                    0: {
                        content: "<div class='cluster cluster-1'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
                        width: 90,
                        height: 80
                    },
                    // This style will be used for clusters with more than 20 markers
                    20: {
                        content: "<div class='cluster cluster-2'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
                        width: 90,
                        height: 80
                    },
                    // This style will be used for clusters with more than 50 markers
                    50: {
                        content: "<div class='cluster cluster-3'>CLUSTER_COUNT</div>",
                        width: 90,
                        height: 80
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function(cluster) {
                            map.panTo(cluster.main.getPosition());
                            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 2);
                        }
                    }
                },
                events: {
                    click: function(marker, event, context){                            
                        map.panTo(marker.getPosition());

                        infobox.setContent(context.data);
                        infobox.open(map,marker);

                        // if map is small
                        var iWidth = 260;
                        var iHeight = 300;
                        if((mapDiv.width() / 2) < iWidth ){
                            var offsetX = iWidth - (mapDiv.width() / 2);
                            map.panBy(offsetX,0);
                        }
                        if((mapDiv.height() / 2) < iHeight ){
                            var offsetY = -(iHeight - (mapDiv.height() / 2));
                            map.panBy(0,offsetY);
                        }

                    }
                }
            },"autofit");

            map = mapDiv.gmap3("get");
infobox = new InfoBox({
    pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-50, -65),
    closeBoxURL: '',
    enableEventPropagation: true
});
mapDiv.delegate('.infoBox .close','click',function () {
    infobox.close();
});
// hotfix for chrome on android
mapDiv.delegate('.infoBox div.more-button', 'click', function() {
    window.location = $(this).data('link');
});

if (Modernizr.touch){
    map.setOptions({ draggable : false });
    var draggableClass = 'inactive';
    var draggableTitle = "Activate map";
    var draggableButton = $('<div class="draggable-toggle-button '+draggableClass+'">'+draggableTitle+'</div>').appendTo(mapDiv);
    draggableButton.click(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('active')){
            $(this).removeClass('active').addClass('inactive').text("Activate map");
            map.setOptions({ draggable : false });
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('inactive').addClass('active').text("Deactivate map");
            map.setOptions({ draggable : true });
        }
    });
}
})
```

And my ajax response is the below:

```
> success: function(data) {                             
>               mapDiv.height(500).gmap3({                  
>                   action: 'addMarkers',
>                   marker: {
>                       values: 
>                           data                    
>                   }                   
>                   },"autofit");                   }
```

And this is the array i'm returning from my controller:

```
$ar[] = array("address" =>"{$business['Business']['name']}, {$business['Business']['address1']}, {$business['Business']['location']}",
                            "data" => "'<div class=\"marker-holder\">'+
                                    '<div class=\"marker-content with-image\"><img src=\"img/map-photo/Cars-Lot-For-Sale.jpg\" alt=\"\">'+
                                        '<div class=\"map-item-info\">'+
                                            '<div class=\"title\">'+\"Viktor's Cars\"+'</div>'+
                                            '<div class=\"address\">'+\"107 Montague Street Brooklyn, NY 11201, United States\"+'</div>'+
                                            '<div data-link=\"catalog-item.html\" class=\"more-button\">' + \"VIEW MORE\" + '</div>'+
                                            '</div><div class=\"arrow\"></div><div class=\"close\"></div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'",
                            "options" => array("icon"=> "/img/map-icon/food1.png"));
```

Can someone guide me as to why my infobox isn't popping up please? Also, no JS errors are returned, so there is something wrong with the logic most probably.

many thanks

Comment: by the way, i'm converting the array to json before i return it